# If scrollIntoView working not good enough / scrollIntoView not working / scrollIntoView alternative

Tags: js-scrollintoview

I have faced with the problem that scrollIntoView some times wokrs good, some times no (in most cases not good).So I tried to find an alternative and some kind of it was [this article.](https://medium.com/@vigu_madurai/solved-alternate-to-the-default-scrollintoview-8da76e083066)

But in my program i needed also a horizontal scrolling to element and vertical scrolling showing element in the top of parent window.

So I modifed code from article.

```
/* This is the main function where which pass two ref parameters of Parent element & Child element */
function scrollIntoView(parent, child) {
  const parentBounding = parent.getBoundingClientRect(),
      clientBounding = child.getBoundingClientRect();

  const parentTop = parentBounding.top,
      clientTop = clientBounding.top,
      parentLeft = parentBounding.left,
      clientLeft = clientBounding.left - 400; /* 400 is a shift so that each difference is not nailed to the upper left edge. You can delete it */

  if (parentTop >= clientTop) {
    scrollTo(parent, -(parentTop - clientTop), 300, 'vertical');
  }
  else {
    scrollTo(parent, clientTop - parentTop, 300, 'vertical');
  }

  if (parentLeft >= clientLeft) {
    scrollTo(parent, -(parentLeft - clientLeft), 300, 'horizontal');
  }
  else {
    scrollTo(parent, clientLeft - parentLeft, 300, 'horizontal');
  }
}

function scrollTo(element, to, duration, type) {

  let start = (type == 'vertical') ? element.scrollTop : element.scrollLeft,
      currentTime = 0,
      increment = 20;

  let animateScroll = function() {
    currentTime += increment;

    let val = easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, to, duration);
    if (type == 'vertical') {
      element.scrollTop = val;
    }
    else {
      element.scrollLeft = val;
    }

    if (currentTime < duration) {
      setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
    }
  }

  animateScroll();
}

/* Function for smooth scroll animation with the time duration */
function easeInOutQuad(time, startPos, endPos, duration) {
  time /= duration / 2;
  if (time < 1) return (endPos / 2) * time * time + startPos;
  time--;
  return (-endPos / 2) * (time * (time - 2) - 1) + startPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is experimental (At the time of my comment)
Both scrollIntoView() its scrollIntoViewOption.